# MySQL Notifications Query - Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, notifications

I am trying to create a query that can handle grabbing values from multiple tables, ordering by each table's timestamp, and outputting the resulting data into one data stream. This will be like the notification area in Facebook or Google+.

I will need to access data from a variety of tables all with various fields. For instance - Actions History, Announcements, and Events for starters.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what youre looking for is [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) query, ie

```
(SELECT timestamp_field, ... FROM Actions WHERE ...)
UNION
(SELECT timestamp_field, ... FROM History WHERE ...)
ORDER BY timestamp_field;
```